# commit file from a web application (spring boot) into git remote repository without first cloning the repo as local? is this possible

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, github

I am sure this must have been solved before, but I could not get a concrete example.
I have a web app which is taking input from user for some config mgmt and creating an XML. The XML is supposed to be checked into a git repo.

Being new to Git a little clueless, all examples point that we need to have a local repository cloned on disk before doing a git add and finally a git commit and git push.

My question is can't we avoid cloning locally and do a git commit and git push programmatically (java) for that given file [myrepo/config/my-config.xml]

Any example really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not do commit and push without local repository.

Comment: GitHub (there is a tag in the question) allows to add/edit/delete files in the web interface; commits are created accordingly.